# Как эмулировать такой запрос? (google recaptcha)

Tags: python, captcha, google-recaptcha

Всем привет. Есть сайт `youla.ru`, хочу сделать там авторизацию на запросах, на языке Python.
Я заметил что при пост запросе отправляется некий `requestid`

[image: запрос на авторизацию]

Потом я заметил что этот `requestid` получает из ответа другого запроса а именно, https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Lfvp3cUAAAAAPcIieBxiskFJsp-PndNyQwYzMze
(по всей видемости это капча невидемая)
В чем заключается проблема. Хочу этот запрос сэмулировать но в вкладе запрос вижу такие данные впервые, т.е. не могу понять как их отправить на Python и как они вообще называются. (был бы это `json` сразу бы понял)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас получилось разобраться?
У меня такая же проблема

Comment: Это обычная капча как оказалось.)

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне помочь, какие данные мы отправляем на адрес api2\reload? не могу понять(
Прошу прощения у меня нет достаточно репутации чтобы оставлять комментарии..